# How to control no. of requests per user in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am doing load testing for one ecommerce website. I am using `Ultimate thread group`.

Now I want to send per user only 1 request. So for ex: If 500 users then only 500 request should send. How can I achieve it using `Ultimate thread group`?

Why I want above because I am doing whole process like login, select product, add to cart and checkout. So it should do everything only once per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test design is a little bit flaky as given each user does login, select product, add to cart and checkout you will have at least 4 requests per user which gives 2000 requests in total (doesn't include embedded resources calls). You can use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to group these requests into one "workflow" however it won't limit actual amount of requests.

- If you need to run your workflow by each user only once you may run into a situation when either load will be less than 500 concurrent users or test duration will be less than 30/60 minutes, see [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)
- If you add more iterations each user will be executing your workflow more than once

Normally web test plan should look as follows:

- Given each user executes test scenario steps and acting like a real user
- Gradually increase the number of users unless application response time becomes too high or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first
- Analyze results, identify the bottleneck, report your findings

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the duration of the test is 1 hour. First user completes the workflow you had mentioned in the first 10 mins itself. What should happen after the workflow for the user? Should the thread be idle for the remaining 50 mins?

I think you should use the regular `Thread Group` with 500 threads and loop count as 1. `Ultimate Thread Group` is for duration based tests. You could use `Once Only Controller` as a workaround inside to do the action only once for the user. But it is an ugly approach.

Comment: @vins- Thanks for answer. With regular thread group I think I won't be able to check like how many users server can handle in 30 minutes or 1 hour. so I preferred ultimate thread group. Please guide me if I am incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller).

> The Throughput Controller allows the user to control how often it is executed. There are two modes:

- percent execution
- total executions

**Percent executions**
causes the controller to execute a certain percentage of the iterations through the test plan.

**Total executions**
causes the controller to stop executing after a certain number of executions have occurred.
Like the Once Only Controller, this setting is reset when a parent Loop Controller restarts.